# Warning: Division by zero in loop

Tags: php, loops, warnings

I have this code:

```
for ($y = 0; $y < $numRows; $y++) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numRows; $i++) {
        ${'contaH' . $i}[]=${'arrHoriz' . $i}[$y]/$arr[$y];
    }
}

echo $contaH0[0]."\n";
```

that output is:

```
Warning: Division by zero in C:\Users\xx\VertrigoServ\www\AHP\new\demo.php on line 66
Warning: Division by zero in C:\Users\xx\VertrigoServ\www\AHP\new\demo.php on line 66
Warning: Division by zero in C:\Users\xx\VertrigoServ\www\AHP\new\demo.php on line 66
Warning: Division by zero in C:\Users\xx\VertrigoServ\www\AHP\new\demo.php on line 66
0.300618921309
```

but if i change this line:

```
${'contaH' . $i}[]=${'arrHoriz' . $i}[$y]/$arr[$y];
```

to

```
${'contaH' . $i}[]=${'arrHoriz' . $i}[$y]/$arr[0];
```

the output is:

```
0.300618921309
```

What is the reason of the warning in first code ?

Comment: Isn't the warning obvious enough?

Comment: @ marabutt >>> array(3) { [0]=> string(6) "113.1 " [1]=> string(5) "53.3 " [2]=> string(3) "46 " }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either `$arr` doesn't have as many elements as you think it does, or it has a lot of 0 or empty elements.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that in your loop, `$arr[$y]` isn't always equal to 0. Somewhere in your array it's zero (or not defined). You should do a check to see if your denominator is zero before doing any division and properly handle the case where it's zero.